aioGoogle not running asynchronously
I'm trying to send requests to Google Calendar asynchonously using aiogoogle but they're running synchonously, here's the code:
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from aiogoogle.auth.creds import UserCreds, ClientCreds
from aiogoogle import Aiogoogle


async def list_events(ranges_list: tuple[datetime, datetime]):

    async with Aiogoogle(user_creds=user_creds, client_creds=client_creds) as aiogoogle:
        service = await aiogoogle.discover("calendar", "v3")
        
        tasks = [aiogoogle.as_user(
            service.events.list(timeMin=timeMin, timeMax=timeMax, calendarId=CALENDAR_ID)
        ) for timeMin, timeMax in ranges_list]

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return [[event['summary'] for event in calendar['items']] for calendar in results]

async def main():
    ranges_list = [(
        datetime(2024, 5, i).isoformat() + '+02:00',
        datetime(2024, 5, i +1).isoformat() + '+02:00'
    )  for i in range(10,25)]

    for event in await list_events(ranges_list):
        print(event)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong but they aren't running in parallel

Async != parallel. What output/result do you get, what do you expect?

how do you know that they don't run in parallel?

Execution time increases linearly as more tasks are added

I resolved using the bare http api request and using aiohttp instead of aiogoogle
